# Problem Importing and Writing a Float to a Text File on Interval

Tags: python, text-files, file-import

I am making a Python program that simulates a stock market for Zer0 Coin (ZRC). Basically, every 2 seconds the program will get a new "token" that is usually around 0.8 to 1.2. The token is written to Token.txt every time it generates a new one to save it. When the program starts, it should import it for use.

I am having problems writing and importing the text file because it needs to be written as a float and imported as a float. I am new to text files in Python, so I kind of threw together a lot of file stuff and it didn't work. I would like to know how to import a float from a text file. I also need to know how to replace the previous text file number with a new one every 2 seconds. I tried to do this, and it kept writing a ton of spaces before the number, preventing it from importing as a float the next time I ran it.

It should be able to run multiple times, using the last "token" from the previous run.

The Token.py file will start out as just 1.0.

**ComputerInvest.py File**

```
import time
import random
import decimal

userUSD = 0
tokenInterval = 2

def user():
    print('Running as User...\n')
    userUSD = input('USD Input:  ')
    ZRC = int(userUSD)
    print('USD: ' + str(userUSD) + '  is now equal to ZRC: ' + str(ZRC))
    invest(ZRC)

def invest(ZRCl):
    global token
    seconds = int(input('\nRepeat for time (seconds):  '))
    print('Running Investment...\n\n')
    tokenFW = open(r"Token.txt","r+")
    start = time.time()
    while time.time() - start < seconds:
        time.sleep(int(tokenInterval))
        upordown = random.randint(0,5)
        step = float(decimal.Decimal(random.randrange(0,10000))/1000000000)

        if upordown == 1 or upordown == 2:
            token = token + step
        elif upordown == 4 or upordown == 5:
            token = token - step
        elif upordown == 3:
            pass

        ZRCl = ZRCl * token
        ZRCf = format(ZRCl, ".4f")
        tokenFW.truncate(0)
        tokenFW.write(str(token))
        print('Token:  ' + str(token))
        print('New ZRC Amount:  ' + str(ZRCf) + '\n')

    print('Investment End')
    print('Final New ZRC Amount:  ' + ZRCf)
    ZRC = ZRCf
    USD = ZRC
    tokenFW.close()

tokenF = open(r"Token.txt","r")
token = float(tokenF.read())
tokenF.close()
user()
```

I am also kind of new to StackOverflow, so if I did something wrong please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're writing the token multiple times in a loop while the file is still open and in use by the program.  I'd suggest making use of a `with` statement instead of using the file `close()` method (which commits the changes/writing).  The with statement will keep the file open only until the commands complete, then close and save automatically.

```
def invest(ZRCl):
    global token
    seconds = int(input('\nRepeat for time (seconds):  '))
    print('Running Investment...\n\n')
    tokenFW = 'Token.txt'
    start = time.time()
    while time.time() - start < seconds:
        time.sleep(int(tokenInterval))
        upordown = random.randint(0,5)
        step = float(decimal.Decimal(random.randrange(0,10000))/1000000000)

        if upordown == 1 or upordown == 2:
            token = token + step
        elif upordown == 4 or upordown == 5:
            token = token - step
        elif upordown == 3:
            pass

        ZRCl = ZRCl * token
        ZRCf = format(ZRCl, ".4f")
        with open(tokenFW, 'w') as f:
            f.write(str(token))
        print('Token:  ' + str(token))
        print('New ZRC Amount:  ' + str(ZRCf) + '\n')

    print('Investment End')
    print('Final New ZRC Amount:  ' + ZRCf)
    ZRC = ZRCf
    USD = ZRC

with open(r'Token.txt', 'r') as f:
    token = float(f.read())
user()
```